# Is it possible to merge @media & class rules?

Tags: css

I wonder if it is possible to merge the `@media` & `body.dark` to avoid duplication?

Example:

```css
:root {
  --color: #000;
  --bg: #fff;
  --hover: #eee;
}

@media screen and (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  :root {
    --color: #fff;
    --bg: #000;
    --hover: #555;
  }  
}

body.dark {
  --color: #fff;
  --bg: #000;
  --hover: #555;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the specific example given you could turn things round

```
:root, body.dark {
  --color: #fff;
  --bg: #000;
  --hover: #555;
}

@media screen and (prefers-color-scheme: light) {
  :root {
    --color: #000;
    --bg: #fff;
    --hover: #eee;
  }  
}
```